# Cannot open a tensorflow session

Tags: gpu, nvidia, tensorflow

When I try to open a tensorflow session, I get the following error:

```
2017-09-24 10:49:20.526121: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.342
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.87GiB
2017-09-24 10:49:20.599629: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x3dcf7e0 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-09-24 10:49:20.599947: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:171] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 1: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/python-envs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1486, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/user/python-envs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 621, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/user/python-envs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

I have two GPUS in my system. One for display and another for compute:

```
GPU0 (display) : Nvidia NVS 310 
GPU1 (compute) : Nvidia Geforce GTX 970
Graphics Driver: 384.66
CUDA version   : 8
cuDNN version  : v6 for CUDA 8 (April 27, 2017)
Operating Sys. : Ubuntu 16.04
```

Has anyone else had this issue? How do I go ahead debugging/fixing this?

**NOTE**: I did try to open an issue on Github. But before I finished, I was requested to look for issues raised earlier on SO or ask there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that tensorflow tries to grab all available GPUs for computation as shown in the Github issue linked below. Setting the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to the device I want to use for computation did the trick.

Possibly related issue on Github includes: [Segmentation fault when GPUs are already used](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/152)

One can check the device id on Ubuntu by running the `nvidia-smi` utility.